# Dev Machine JBoss Deploy, Quick Refresh of Webpage with Changes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss, gulp

I have a dev machine, which deploys a java project to a local jboss server.

I have an IntelliJ maven project that has some html/js/jsp/servlets, etc. Is there a way to edit the code of the html/js files and then do a refresh of the webpage and see the updated changes without having to redeploy?

When doing just front end apps, I can accomplish this with a node server using `gulp watch`.

I'm hoping for something similar with my jboss server setup (intent is to simplify architecture and try to get the same front end development speed but have it all contained within a war). If I need to some how use `gulp watch` with maven, I'm good with that too, as long as I can make changes in the front end code (html/js, I assume changes to jsp/servlets would require a redeploy) and refresh the webpage and see the changes right away. I've also seen people write scripts to copy files from source into an exploded war before, but nothing that was automatic like `gulp watch`. My googles have failed me, anyone know how to accomplish this?